# Why does my sidebar get dragged down on this specific uid?

Tags: sidebar

My sidebar is getting dragged down on uid=1: http://www.mrgeek.me/contributors/?uid=1

Now, the other contributor pages have the same underlying markup, yet they work fine.

For example, uid=3, http://www.mrgeek.me/contributors/?uid=3.

I need to know what is happening and what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for unclosed elements like a div tag or unordered list tag which looks something like this:

```
/div>
/ul>
```

You've got 30 errors on the page and about 4 unclosed elements.

You can test any url using http://validator.w3.org/

Here's some of the results:

Error Line 1277, Column 7: End tag for body seen, but there were unclosed elements.

Error Line 839, Column 33: Unclosed element div.

Error Line 739, Column 19: Unclosed element div.

Comment: There are exactly the same amount of opening div tags and closing div tags in both the uid=1 and uid=3, yet it only occurs for uid=1. I even did some code differences using an online tool and still not solved. Any help is much appreciated. Been cracking this for hours :(

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. It was a stupid unescaped HTML character from one of my old commenting systems.